# How to fix "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/TOM8iPnfdiVaFAXvjBcqaIaDKdNJROB5fEQWVvgc.jpeg 404 (Not Found)" ERROR in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

Initially My code was functioning well and I was able to load a background image in my header from the storage folder but today it's broken and background Image is not showing in the fronted and when I inspect my page I see the following error "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/TOM8iPnfdiVaFAXvjBcqaIaDKdNJROB5fEQWVvgc.jpeg 404 (Not Found)"

What could be the problem!

My header,

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url(@yield('bg-img'))">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 40px; width: 100%">@yield('title')</h1>
                    <h1>@yield('about-title')</h1>
                        @yield('sub-heading')</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

My post.blade.php file,

```
@extends('user.app')

@section('bg-img', Storage::disk('local')->url($post->image))
@section('title', $post->title)
```

Comment: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Tried, same problem still!
@STA

Comment: @STA I think there was a problem with my symlink. I deleted it then created it again and it worked!